# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ Gromov-Hyperbolic?

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

If $G$ is a finitely-generated group, then we say that $G$ is Gromov-Hyperbolic if it's Cayley Graph, $\operatorname{Cay}(G, S)$, is a Gromov-Hyperbolic metric space.

Now in the case of the group of integers under addition $\mathbb{Z} = \langle g \rangle$, we have that $\operatorname{Cay}(\mathbb{Z}, \{g\})$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}$ and we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a Gromov-Hyperbolic metric space, so it follows that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not Gromov Hyperbolic.

However, I have seen in some notes on Geometric Group Theory that $\mathbb{Z}$ is Gromov Hyperbolic. Why is this so? And what is the error I'm making?

Comment: I think you will find that ${\mathbb R}$ is Gromov-hyperbolic, with thninness constant $0$. The same applies to all (finitely generated) free groups - their Cayley graphs have thinness constant $0$.

Comment: "We know that ${\mathbb R}$ is not Gromov-hyperbolic" is plain wrong; where did it come from?

Comment: It may be a confusion between $\mathbf{R}$ viewed as metric space or as discrete group. As discrete group, it's not hyperbolic. As locally compact group (usual topology) it's hyperbolic, and it is so as metric space.

Answer (score 1):

As metric spaces both $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are Gromov $0$-hyperbolic as can be easily seen from the Gromov four-point condition:

$$(x|z)_o \geq \min((x|y)_o,((y|z)_o) - \delta,$$

with $(x|y)_o = \frac{1}{2}(d(x,o) + d(y,o) - d(x,y))$. This has to hold for any $x,y,z,o \in X$ for your space $X$ to be $\delta$ hyperbolic. Here $\delta = 0$.

Note that in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ the triangles are degenerate
and we have the metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$. Plugging this information in to the above
four-point condition, we can see that it is satisfied for all points with $\delta = 0$.